# How to write an Oracle sql like java split function?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Now I want to write the sql,if I passed the keyword like  `Aaron` ,then I search the result:

`select * from worker where name like %Aaron%`

if I passed the keyword like  `Aaron Alina Wendy`,then I search the result:

`select * from worker where name like %Aaron% or name like '%Alina%' or name like '%Wendy%'`

I know there must have a easy way like split function or other way to get the search result,and I do not need to split the keyword to splice the sql statement,How to do that?Can I do the job like this:

```
select * from worker where fn_getSearchCondition('Aaron Alina Wendy')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select w.*
  from worker w
 where regexp_like(w.name,'Aaron|Alina|Wendy');
```

If your list of search conditions is variable you can use the REPLACE() function to convert the space characters to the pipe delimiter to compose the regular expression:

```
regexp_like(w.name, replace('Aaron Alina Wendy',' ','|') )
```

Comment: If the search condition like regexp_like(w.name, replace('Aaron&nbsp;&nbsp;Alina Wendy',' ','|') ),it will return all result.This is not what I want.Aaron      Alina  has more than one blank space.

Comment: You can use the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function to replace all consecutive spaces with a single pipe like so: `REGEXP_REPLACE('Aaron  Alina Wendy',' +','|')` where there are two or more spaces between Aaron and Alina.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT w.* 
FROM worker w
JOIN table(
   DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY('Aaron', 'Alina', 'Wendy')
) x
ON w.name LIKE '%'||x.column_value||'%'
```